# Power Query. Как преобразовать окончание слова в зависимости от текущего месяца?

Tags: excel

Есть код:

```
'= "Сейчас месяц " &  Text.Upper(Date.MonthName(DateTime.LocalNow(), "ru-RU")) &
     ", это " & Text.From(Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow())) & "-й месяц года."'
```

На выходе: "Сейчас СЕНТЯБРЬ, это 9-*й* месяц года."

Подскажите, что нужно дописать в формуле, чтобы на выходе, был такой результат (в зависимости от того, какая сейчас дата):

```
Сейчас месяц ЯНВАРЬ, и это 1-ый месяц года.
Сейчас месяц ФЕВРАЛЬ, и это 2-ой месяц года.
Сейчас месяц МАРТ, и это 3-ий месяц года.
Сейчас месяц АПРЕЛЬ, и это 4-ый месяц года.
Сейчас месяц МАЙ, и это 5-ый месяц года.
Сейчас месяц ИЮНЬ, и это 6-ой месяц года.
Сейчас месяц ИЮЛЬ, и это 7-ой месяц года.
Сейчас месяц АВГУСТ, и это 8-ой месяц года.
Сейчас месяц СЕНТЯБРЬ, и это 9-ый месяц года.
Сейчас месяц ОКТЯБРЬ, и это 10-ый месяц года.
Сейчас месяц НОЯБРЬ, и это 11-ый месяц года.
Сейчас месяц ДЕКАБРЬ, и это 12-ый месяц года.
```

Comment: Только PQ, формулой листа не принимается?

Comment: Только с использованием языка "М".

Comment: Может, кому поможет функциями Excel (в `A2` - дата): `="Сейчас месяц "&ПРОПИСН(ТЕКСТ(A2;"ММММ"))&", и это "&МЕСЯЦ(A2)&"-"&ПСТР("ыоиыыоооыыыы";МЕСЯЦ(A2);1)&"й месяц года."`